# distanced always by a sense of

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "distanced by" mean in:

"The images in themselves are as grotesque as those in Hirst’s catalogue pictures but taken out of documentary context, juxtaposed with other material and distanced always by a sense of the artist’s hovering and appalled presence, they are rendered art."

Comment: In that passage, *distance* is a verb, as in "to distance oneself" or "to keep at arm's length". The artcrit interpretation of what that *means*, I'll leave to others.

Comment: @Dan Bron So, does "distanced always by a sense of the artist’s hovering and appalled presence" mean "the artwork being empty of the presence of the artist" or the contrary?

Comment: As I said, I'll leave the artcrit interpretation of what it *means*, to others.

Comment: @Dan, user127733: The *exact* meaning (if indeed there is one, though I think chasly may be overstating the case below) is an Off Topic matter of opinion. But if A (the images) are *distanced **by*** B (a sense of the artist's presence) this must surely imply that (figuratively, at least) the artist ***is*** "present". If not, what could be doing this "distancing"?

Answer (score 4):

I originally made this as a comment but I'll expand it into an answer.

Usually we can explain what a word or phrase means. However this passage is written in *artcrit* as Dan Bron aptly puts it.  It is a subgenre of English closely related to another that is known technically as [BS](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/bs).

Unlike other languages, *artcrit* is not intended to be understood.  It has several reasons for its existence.

1. It provides employment for writers who have no talent of their own—either in the field they are writing about or indeed as writers.
2. It is used to fill the empty pages between pictures in journals whose sole purpose is to be prominently displayed in the waiting rooms of medical practitioners.
3. It keeps alive some archaic words that should have been eliminated from the language a long time ago because of their uselessness in normal discourse.
4. It allows semi-literate and untalented, but pretentious readers to claim intellectual superiority that they don't possess, by virtue of owning works written in the language. This allows them and the writer to bask in a shared warm and fuzzy sensation of smuggery.

**Answer**

Do not try to derive any meaning from the passage—there is none nor is there intended to be. The proper way to read it is to allow the words to wash over you in such a way as to to confirm your own prejudices and preconceptions.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for *The proper way to read it is to allow the words to wash over you in such a way as to to confirm your own prejudices and preconceptions*!

Comment: +1 simply because that answer really IS writing, and far more insightful, accurate and entertaining writing than the passage in the original question could even dream of being.