# an unresolved cycle of fear and the desire for consummation

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "desire for consummation" mean in this context?

Context:

> The original exhibition’s centrepiece display of sickening body images
>   was mediated through distancing devices – literary association,
>   cultural cliché, blurred photographs, drawings, all part of a
>   reassuringly calm gallery ethos. Perversely, however, they served only
>   to stimulate the viewer’s capacity to imagine a horror which is yet
>   more horrible than the real, as if the artifice deliberately withholds
>   its true potential, thereby creating an unresolved cycle of fear and
>   the desire for consummation.

Art and Science, Sian Ede

Comment: If you have to ask so many questions about what Sian Ede means, maybe she's just hard to understand as a writer.

Comment: @sumelic : That isn't writing IMHO; rather it's a bucket of random but pretentious words loaded into the business end of a blunderbuss and fired at a word processor screen in a desperate attempt to appear erudite. Chasly from UK nailed the writing style in his reply here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275837/distanced-always-by-a-sense-of  To user127733, pay close heed to what Chasly said. Don't bother trying to interpret what has been said, just dump the book. There are plenty of others out there which aim to enlighten the reader rather than... well, what Chasly said, basically.

Comment: @AlanK is right. This is absolutely horrible. If I were to guess, I'd say the "writer" is saying the exhibition was set up in such a way as to give the visitors a lingering feeling of fear. When they left the exhibition, this feeling stuck around enough that the visitors felt incomplete: they needed to "finish" the feeling to get over it an move on.